# Automorphisms of a vertex-transitive graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $\Gamma = (V,E)$ be a vertex-transitive finite graph with $|V| \geq 2$ and $G := \operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$. Then there exists $1_G \not= g \in G$ such that $x^g \not= x$ for all $x \in V$. So there is an automorphism of $\Gamma$ without any fixed vertex.

Let's assume that every $g \in G$ has a fixed vertex $v_g \in V$ such that $(v_g)^g = v_g$. Since $V$ has at least two elements, there exists an $w \in V$ with $w^h = v_g$ for an $h \in G$ because $\Gamma$ is vertex-transitive.

Now I used every condition of the claim but I still don't see where to get to.

Comment: Use Burnside's lemma. It's actually a theorem about transitive permutation groups.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have considered Burnside's lemma but it totally makes sense. We know that $G$ is transitive on $V$, so we have one orbit thus: $1 = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum\limits_{g \in G} V_g$ with $V_g := \{v \in V | v^g = v\}$. Hence $\sum\limits_{g \in G} V_g = |G|$. We already know that $1_G$ is fixing the set $V$, so under upper assumption $\sum\limits_{g \in G} V_g = |V| + \sum\limits_{1_G \not= g \in G} V_g \geq |V| + |G| - 1$ and since $|V| \geq 2$ we get the contradiction. Thus there exists $g \in G$ with $V_g = \emptyset$.

Comment: @PeterMcCoy You should turn your comment into an answer (and accept it) to move this off the unanswered queue.